# Exporting Point Cloud as .RAW

Tags: vb.net, export, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

I am working with a large set of points and I am looking to export the point cloud to the .raw format. I searched for how to do this in Java, and it came back with the java.io.BufferedOutputStream class that nicely takes care of my search, but I have yet to find something similar for VB .NET . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `BufferedStream` class is probably the closest thing in the .NET framework to the `BufferedOutputStream` class in Java.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx